# Storing a pointer to a user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I have a user control that I want to reference at postback programatically.

In order to do so, I'll need to persist information in viewstate.

I have 2 options:

1. Store the control ID in viewstate and find the control on the page each time
2. Store the control in viewstate i.e. WebControl and do not need to
   find each time

Is there any downside to going with option 2 over 1?

Comment: I may be missing something but why does the ID change?

Comment: The ID doesn't change but for example, I have a customer validator that references back to the multiple controls on postback - so I need to find which controls are associated with my validator and perform actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot store any 'object' in ViewState, as it is created every time during `Load` phase, and dies during `Unload`. Control cannot be serialized. Go with the option 1.